# How to create an HTML element in Javascript with it maintaining only its own properties?

Tags: javascript, html

In javascript, I want to create a function that will create a new um.... This:

```html
<style>
body{overflow:hidden;}

#b{
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
border:0px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.m{position:absolute;left:50%;}
.r{float:right;}
.r{float:left;}


.l{left: 0%; margin-right:50px; position:absolute;}
.r{left: 100%; margin-left:50px; position:sticky;}

#wiow {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid rgb(48,48,114);
  overflow:auto;
  resize:both;
  min-width:20%;
  min-height:10%;
  box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,1) 1px 2px 8px;
  border-radius:4px 4px 0px 0px;
}

#wiowheader {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(24,24,57), rgb(48,48,114));
  color: #fff;
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
  height:20px;
}

#program {
    width:100%;
    height:99%;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:-20px;
    padding:0px;

}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color:rgb(24,24,57);
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
}
</style>


<div id="wiow">
  <div id="wiowheader">
  
  <button id="b" onClick="closeWiow()" class="r"><img width="20px" src="./x.png"></img></button>
  <button id="b" class="m"><img width="20px" style="margin-left:-10px;" src="./i.png"></img></button>
  <button id="b" onClick="fullWiow()" class="l"><img width="20px" src="./s.png"></img></button>
  
  </div>
  <div id="program">
    <h1>sdfsdfsdfsdf</h1>
    <p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var wiow = document.getElementById("wiow");

dragElement(wiow);

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}

function fullWiow(){
    if (wiow.style.left == "-0.5px" && wiow.style.top == "-0.5px" && wiow.style.width == "100vw" && wiow.style.height == "100vh") {
    wiow.style.left = "200px";
    wiow.style.top = "200px";
    wiow.style.width = "200px";
    wiow.style.height = "150px";
    } else {
    wiow.style.left = "-0.5px";
    wiow.style.top = "-0.5px";
    wiow.style.width = "100vw";
    wiow.style.height = "100vh";
    }
}
function closeWiow(){
    
    wiow.style.display = "none";
    wiow.innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

I would like to create a function to create that, but have it keep its scripts to itself and not bother a different one of those.

When I call the function it should create a new tab thingy and behave as itself without interfeiring with other tab thingys.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to type out all of the necessary code, but you would want to use `document.createElement("desired element"),` and then manipulate said elements with DOM, so `document.getElementBy[whatever method you want]().style.[desired style].value =`  for the styles, and `document.getElementBy[whatever method you want]().innerHTML =` for the text, and `document.getElementBy[whatever method you want]().class/id/name/value =`  to change arbitrary attributes. because you would be creating a function to preform, this action, everything is local, meaning your tabs will keep their scripts to themselves. if you want me to go into more detail with the code itself and write it out more, don't hesitate to reach out, and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a small incomplete example of how you would be able to do it. You should be able to re-purpose it for your needs. The changes I made were primarily changing the id's to classes since id's should only be used on a unique element and since you are creating multiple of these styling them with classes is easier.

Let me know if you need further guidance. As it stands right now the below snippet creates a new **thingy** on button click each time as you wanted. You'll just need to to adjust by creating a variable that is randomized or that grows (ex: with a for loop and an incrementor on each loop which is triggered onclick of the button) to then position these **thingies** (currently the new ones just layer on top which you can see by dragging the corner out) where you wan them on the page which you didnt disclose in the question so I am leaving up to you..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    body{overflow:hidden;}
    
    #b{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
    
    .m{position:absolute;left:50%;}
    .r{float:right;}
    .r{float:left;}
    
    
    .l{left: 0%; margin-right:50px; position:absolute;}
    .r{left: 100%; margin-left:50px; position:sticky;}
    
    .wiow {
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 9;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      border: 1px solid rgb(48,48,114);
      overflow:auto;
      resize:both;
      min-width:20%;
      min-height:10%;
      box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,1) 1px 2px 8px;
      border-radius:4px 4px 0px 0px;
    }
    
    .wiowheader {
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 0px;
      cursor: move;
      z-index: 10;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(24,24,57), rgb(48,48,114));
      color: #fff;
      position:sticky;
      top:0px;
      height:20px;
    }
    
    .program {
        width:100%;
        height:99%;
        background-color:white;
        margin-top:-20px;
        padding:0px;
    
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color:rgb(24,24,57);
    }
     
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); 
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); 
    }
    </style>
    
    
    <div class="wiow" id="wiow">
      <div class="wiowheader" id="wiowheader">
      
      <button id="b" onClick="closeWiow()" class="r"><img width="20px" src="./x.png"></img></button>
      <button id="b" class="m"><img width="20px" style="margin-left:-10px;" src="./i.png"></img></button>
      <button id="b" onClick="fullWiow()" class="l"><img width="20px" src="./s.png"></img></button>
      
      </div>
      <div id="program">
        <h1>Test 1:</h1>
        <p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 50%;" id="test" ></div>
    
    <script>
    var wiow = document.getElementsByClassName("wiow");
    
    dragElement(wiow);
    
    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }
    
      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }
    
      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
      }
    
      function closeDragElement() {
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
    
    function fullWiow(){
        if (wiow.style.left == "-0.5px" && wiow.style.top == "-0.5px" && wiow.style.width == "100vw" && wiow.style.height == "100vh") {
        wiow.style.left = "200px";
        wiow.style.top = "200px";
        wiow.style.width = "200px";
        wiow.style.height = "150px";
        } else {
        wiow.style.left = "-0.5px";
        wiow.style.top = "-0.5px";
        wiow.style.width = "100vw";
        wiow.style.height = "100vh";
        }
    }
    function closeWiow(){
        
        wiow.style.display = "none";
        wiow.innerHTML = "";
    }
    </script>

    <script>
      var html = [
          '<div id="wiow" class="wiow">',
              '<div id="wiow-header" class="wiow-header">',
                '<button id="b" onClick="closeWiow()" class="r"><img width="20px" src="./x.png"></img></button>',
                '<button id="b" class="m"><img width="20px" style="margin-left:-10px;" src="./i.png"></img></button>',
                '<button id="b" onClick="fullWiow()" class="l"><img width="20px" src="./s.png"></img></button>',
              '</div>',
              '<div id="program" class="program">',
                '<h1>Test 2:</h1>',
                '<p>sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</p>',
              '</div>',
          '</div>'
      ].join("\n");
      
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickMe").click(function(){
          $("#test").append(html); 
        }); 
    });

         
    </script>
    <button id="clickMe" style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 100px;">Add Another!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what the JQuery does. I don't use JQuery

Comment: @Mr.CringeKid The document ready makes sure the rest of the page has loaded first and the #clickMe sets a click event that is associated with clicking on the #clickMe button. It then appends the html template to the #test div.